# Dojo unmovable stencil

Tags: dojo

I am drawing stencils using Dojo and I need to make some of the stencils "unmovable" - that is, when a user clicks on the stencil, it is not able to be dragged around the screen.

I guess there's not a lot of code to post here as I'm struggling with the Dojo docs to see if this is possible. I'm adding my stencil using the following line of code:

```
dojoDrawing.addStencil("rect", {
    x : someXVal,
    y : someYVal,
    width : someWidth,
    height : someHeight
});
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't seem ideal, I was able to accomplish what I wanted by making the stencil `disabled`:

```
var stencil = dojoDrawing.addStencil("rect", {
    x : someXVal,
    y : someYVal,
    width : someWidth,
    height : someHeight
});

stencil.disable();
```

This changes the stencil colors to the `disabled` state and makes it not selectable and therefore not movable.